# How to publish a python CLI built with Pyinquirer?

Tags: python, command, command-line-interface

I have created a python script (CLI Tool) using Pyinquirer, but am unsure on how to go about publishing it.
My end goal is for other users to be able to call the script like so after downloading:

```
COMMAND_NAME run
```

Please point me in the right direction to try to achieve this goal. Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to publish my CLI tool for people to download, so when they run a specific command then it will execute the file and run the program.